# Semgrep: Looking for wrong import

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, gettext, semgrep

How would I go on about making Semgrep check if my codebase is importing functions from the wrong place? E.g. in my django project:

`from gettext import gettext` but we should really do `from django.utils.translation import gettext`

Any ideas on how to achieve this with semgrep?

Answer (score 7):

Does this do what you want? Here's a live example link: https://semgrep.dev/s/0n0w

```
rules:
- id: import-from-wrong-module
  patterns:
    - pattern: |
        from $X import gettext
    - pattern-not: |
        from my.special.module import gettext
  message: Please import gettext from my.special.module
  severity: ERROR
```